# Why I am getting the error for GroupShuffleSplit (train test split)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have 2 datasets and applying 5 different ML models.

Dataset 1:

```
def dataset_1():
    ...
    ...
    bike_data_hours = bike_data_hours[:500]
    X = bike_data_hours.iloc[:, :-1].values
    y = bike_data_hours.iloc[:, -1].values
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
    return X_train, X_test, y_train.reshape(-1, 1), y_test.reshape(-1, 1)
```

The shape is `(400, 14) (100, 14) (400, 1) (100, 1)`. The `dtypes: object` (int64, float64).

Dataset 2:

```
def dataset_2():
    ...
    ...
    final_movie_df = final_movie_df[:500]
    X = final_movie_df.iloc[:, :-1]
    y = final_movie_df.iloc[:, -1]
    gs = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=2, test_size=0.2)
    train_ix, test_ix = next(gs.split(X, y, groups=X.UserID))
    X_train = X.iloc[train_ix]
    y_train = y.iloc[train_ix]
    X_test = X.iloc[test_ix]
    y_test = y.iloc[test_ix]
    return X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.values.reshape(-1,1).shape, y_test.values.reshape(-1,1).shape
```

The shape is `(400, 25) (100, 25) (400, 1) (100, 1)`. The `dtypes: object` (int64, float64).

I am using different models. The code is

```
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = dataset
    fold_residuals, fold_dfs = [], []
    kf = KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True)
    for train_index, _ in kf.split(X_train):
        if reg_name == "RF" or reg_name == "SVR":
            preds = regressor.fit(X_train[train_index], y_train[train_index].ravel()).predict(X_test)
        elif reg_name == "Knn-5":
            preds = regressor.fit(X_train[train_index], np.ravel(y_train[train_index], order="C")).predict(X_test)
        else:
            preds = regressor.fit(X_train[train_index], y_train[train_index]).predict(X_test)
```

But I am getting a common error like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667169/key-error-none-of-int64index-dtype-int64-are-in-the-columns), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875744/receiving-keyerror-none-of-int64index-dtype-int64-length-1323-are), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64169166/keyerror-none-of-int64index-12313-n-34534-n-dtype-int64-leng). I have gone through all of these posts, but getting no idea about the error. I have used `iloc` and `values` given as a solution for the visited links.

```
preds = regressor.fit(X_train[train_index], y_train[train_index]).predict(X_test)
  File "/home/fgd/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3030, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
  File "/home/fgd/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1266, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
  File "/home/fgd/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1308, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([  0,   1,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   9,  10,  11,\n            ...\n            387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 395, 397, 399],\n           dtype='int64', length=320)] are in the [columns]"
```

Here, if I use `train_test_split` instead of `GroupShuffleSplit` then the code is working. However, I want to use `GroupShuffleSplit` based on the `UserID` so that the same user does not split for both train and test. Could you tell me how can I solve the problem while I will use `GroupShuffleSplit`?

Could you tell me why I am getting the error for `dataset_2` while `dataset_1` is working fully fine (and the `shape` and `dtypes`) are the same for both datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `values` for your dataset_2. Do changes

```
    X_train = X.iloc[train_ix].values
    y_train = y.iloc[train_ix].values
    X_test = X.iloc[test_ix].values
    y_test = y.iloc[test_ix].values
    return X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.reshape(-1,1).shape, y_test.reshape(-1,1).shape
```

Hopefully now will work